# Is PPDM Lite still available as Geodatabase template?

Tags: esri-geodatabase

I have been looking for a Geodatabase template that conforms to the PPDM Lite standard and believe that one was previously available at [PPDM.org](http://www.ppdm.org/standards/spatial/ppdm_lite_details.html#eight).  However, that page no longer exists and no Geodatabase download is mentioned at the [PPDM Lite 1.1](http://www.ppdm.org/ppdm-standards/ppdm-lite-1-1-data-model) page.

Does anyone know if one is still available anywhere?

Comment: Do you perhaps need to be a member to get to this data?

Comment: Interesting that this page for the [ESRI Petroleum Data Model](http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/datamodel/detail/12) also leads to same dead link.

Comment: That's where I came across the link.  PPDM Lite seems to have been topical from about 2001-2007 and then the trail goes cold so maybe it went into a members only area.  Hopefully, someone from PPDM or PUG may see this and provide an update.

Comment: I am currently trying to implement a standard Geodatabase and I want to look at the PPDM Lite model. Unfortunately when I download the model from the PPDM website I'm unable to do anything with the data. Does anyone have the geodatabase templates still? Many Thanks
Adam

Comment: Andrew do you still have this model on Dropbox?
It would greatly appreciate it if I could download this model.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trail indeed went cold when Ian Batty left, but I posted what I had on Dropbox - it's all available publicly here&there on the web, but as it may require membership I didn't make it public folder. Drop me a note and I'll gladly invite you to the folder in question.

Comment: Thanks Andrew - having reviewed the documentation that was in your DropBox folder, it seems that PPDMLite is not as "ultra-lite" as I was hoping.  Also, I was hoping it might be be available as a Geodatabase of empty feature classes, tables, etc into which I could choose to load some sample data but many thanks for making the info you had available to me.