# Looking for succesful implementaion of PPDM in form of geodatabase

Tags: esri-geodatabase, spatial-database, arcgis-data-model

I am have difficulties in implementing spatial version of Professional Petroleum Data Management (PPDM) for our GIS database.

Does anyone have a reference to a sucessful case of implementing PPDM in a geodatabase?

Or how to build a spatial PPDM database?

Comment: You may want to review http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15503/is-ppdm-lite-still-available-as-a-geodatabase-template but my interest in PPDM was short term and over three years ago.

Comment: Is PPDM an abbreviation of Professional Petroleum Data Management?

Comment: @djq  Yes, PPDM is for Professional Petroleum Data Management

Comment: @PolyGeo thnaks. I reviewed the epost you suggested, but couldn't locate the documentation Andrew talked about. Did you find PPDM lite in geodatabase format? was the data Andrew provided anydifferent than what is on http://PPDM.org?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think I can be of any further help on this.  I notice that [Andrew has blogged recently about PPDM](http://blog.zolnai.ca/2014/11/gulf-of-mexico-ppdm-wells-etl-extract.html).

Answer (score 1):

Just found this, sorry if it's too late. PPDM Spatially Enabling Project didn't gain traction after Ian Batty @maguffyn and I left the project. Here's the latest update I know of http://www.oilit.com/2journal/2article/HTMLArticles/0303_15.htm

ppdm.org under Standards has PPDM Lite 1.1 and sample data for members, and I haven't looked at it for a while, but need to again for a project.